# How to pan using paperjs

Tags: paperjs

I have been trying to figure out how to pan/zoom using onMouseDrag, and onMouseDown in paperjs.
The only reference I have seen has been in coffescript, and does not use the paperjs tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplify Sam P's method some more:

```
var toolPan = new paper.Tool();
toolPan.onMouseDrag = function (event) {
    var offset = event.downPoint - event.point;
    paper.view.center = paper.view.center + offset;
};
```

the event object already has a variable with the start point called [`downPoint`](http://paperjs.org/reference/toolevent/#downpoint).

i have put together a quick [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/fZJNj4IwEIb/yoSLkEV03XjBeNLrJkb3tmxMLaM2lBlSiiZr/O/bFhI8bTk0887XwwuPiESNUR4dKrTyGqWR5NLHsxlckNAIi9ByjXAxorkqKTSgxhrJtnlBN2GgEfZ6NAalhTUQ3mHnhGzPHZV7Jwq6aIwLAnd8dtRCLSuy8TJdJincFN6zVv0iTOF9nqRjz8GJ8WKewmKeFJSsChqXZq01XOGGNRsHMDlpIavJqmeTykiNR0VH6YjRvBJuQi5+FFTYPpv3CH2Qet2IUnVtDh/zEL6symGiVY2Tgp6exz/OskbQtOZb8KcnsMx6J2hY/OWi2NcPcsb0yV2LWyMuruTckbSKKcabG5DAo7fAz+HzuUXvcEhlJd8peOe86pXGR6uhYXwNeFsPvS73XA2cV9QNejgw6MeGBgfsL6YtdyeNG61k9Q/Uy471+O1mi7DH/Ugng6IKVG2Uf/88/wA=) to test this.

Comment: Not sure if this was released at time of writing but with .onMouseDrag you can now do event.delta to get the coordinate difference between mouse down and mouse up

Comment: @ScottAnderson good idea - but after a quick test and read in the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/toolevent/#delta) i found that it is not the same: 
`event.delta = event.point - event.lastPoint` so its the delta from the last time the event fired.

and in the test it was really not the same result:

Comment: http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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

Comment: This approach has a stuttering problem - see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

This took me longer than it should have to figure out.

```
var toolZoomIn = new paper.Tool();
toolZoomIn.onMouseDrag = function (event) {
    var a = event.downPoint.subtract(event.point);
    a = a.add(paper.view.center);
    paper.view.center = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't rely on `event.downPoint` to get the previous point while you're changing the view transform. You have  to save it yourself in view coordinates (as pointed out [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/525#issuecomment-289361893) by Jürg Lehni, developer of Paper.js).

Here's a version that works (also in [this sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/nVE9a8MwEP0rh5bIEEyyunRy14KhoUvSQZEujRr1LkjnejD+77XkLk3oUoEEj3tfh0ZF5hNVo14uKPas1sqyyzigAAfXsSd59Ti0zNGlh0M8UL6nnqx4JmB65j7hEw+ksYIxD2E+91p4hK8Z1NfIH2hlx3mksb5mWlWcpz/to3n/ZW+ZkoDDIGb2/TGpU3+UaKzoEpSfHXdLnL4vVC2h/26bhYUzZ1IKRlCXQje73FAKtEiCcSESDtAZOdetjzagHqNxvk8NbDebNZx8CC0Hjg2sIrrVtIjmjzpGNJdSJ6lm/zZ9Aw==)):

```
let oldPointViewCoords;

function onMouseDown(e) {
    oldPointViewCoords = view.projectToView(e.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(e) {
    const delta = e.point.subtract(view.viewToProject(oldPointViewCoords));
    oldPointViewCoords = view.projectToView(e.point);
    view.translate(delta);
}

view.translate(view.center);
new Path.Circle({radius: 100, fillColor: 'red'});
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It solves my stuttering problem.